# Como hacer un switch en kotlin

Tags: android, android-studio, kotlin

Tengo el siguiente switch de ejemplo en java:

```
int variable = 2;

switch(variable){
     case 1:
     //cosas
     break;

     case 2:
     case 3:
        break;
     case 4:
     //cosas
     break

    default:
    break;
}
```

Lo que quiero con este código java es hacerlo en kotlin, es decir que cuando la variable sea 2 o 3 ejecute lo mismo, justo como lo hice en java.

Comment: En el caso de 2 o 3 serí a :  2, 3 -> print("x tiene el valor de 2 o 3")

Comment: Aparte de todas las respuestas estupendas, quiero añadir que en kotlin, `when` e `if` son expresiones, y retornan valor: `val y = when(x) { //...}`

Comment: Con todo respeto, este tipo de preguntas no deberían existir, sin saber google se que es básico y una busqueda con un mínimo de esfuerzo dará con el resultado.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Revisa la [documentación](https://kotlinlang.org/docs/reference/control-flow.html), [**When**, reemplaza el operador **switch**](https://kotlinlang.org/docs/reference/control-flow.html) de lenguajes tipo C, en este caso [Kotlin](https://kotlinlang.org) . Ejemplo:

```
when (x) {
    1 -> print("x == 1")
    2 -> print("x == 2")
    else -> { // Note the block
        print("x no es 1 o 2")
    }
}
```

Si muchos casos se deben manejar de la misma manera, las condiciones se pueden combinar con una coma:

```
when (x) {
    0, 1 -> print("x == 0 or x == 1")
    else -> print("de otra forma.")
}
```

Podemos usar expresiones arbitrarias (no solo constantes) como condiciones de las ramas

```
when (x) {
    parseInt(s) -> print("s codifica x")
    else -> print("s no codifica a x")
}
```

También podemos verificar un valor que puede ser **in**  o **!in** dentro de un rango o una colección:

```
when (x) {
    in 1..10 -> print("x is in the range")
    in validNumbers -> print("x is valid")
    !in 10..20 -> print("x is outside the range")
    else -> print("none of the above")
}
```

---

Definido lo anterior la versión de **tu código en Kotlin sería**:

```
   var variable = 2

    when (variable) {
        1 -> {
            //Agrega aquí lo que realizaría si variable es igual 1

        }
        2, 3 -> {
            //Agrega aquí lo que realizaría si variable es igual a 2 o 3

        }
        4 -> {
            //Agrega aquí lo que realizaría si variable es igual 4

        } 
        else -> { // Opción default

        }
    }
```

Comment: Me pregunto porque razón el -1? al menos agregar la razón.

Answer (score 2):

En Kotlin se usa la palabra 'when'

```
when (variable) {
    1 -> break
    2,3 -> break
    4 -> break
    else -> { break
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

En kotlin no hay un control llamado `switch` sino [`when`](https://kotlinlang.org/docs/reference/control-flow.html#when-expression):

```
when (x) {
    1 -> print("x == 1")
    2 -> print("x == 2")
    else -> { // Note the block
        print("x is neither 1 nor 2")
    }
}
```

`when` también acepta expresiones:

```
when(x)
{
  is String -> { }
  0, 1 -> // si es igual 0 o 1 
  else -> { }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Puedes utilizar de dos manera :

**1.** Cuando tus casos solo tienen un procedimiento.

```
var variable=2
when (variable) {
1 -> print("No Existe")
2 -> print("Existe")
3 -> print("No Existe")
4 -> print("No Existe")
else -> print("Error")
}
```

**2.** Si tus casos tienen mas de un procedimiento.

```
var variable=2

when (variable) {
1 -> {
      print("No Existe")
     }
2 -> {
      print("Existe")
     }
3 -> {
      print("No Existe")
     }
4 -> {
      print("No Existe")
      }
else -> {
    print("Error")
}
}
```

Nota:Ti tus casos tienen mas procemientos debes utilizar {} si no nada.